# Returning A List Of Quoted Files Paths Using Find

Tags: linux, unix, tar, shell-scripting

I would like to create a tarball that contains files from a directory that have a *ctime* of less than 30 days. Most tutorials I have found have basically recommended doing something like this:

```
tar cvf foo.tar $(find ~/POD -type f -ctime -30)
```

The problem is that a lot of the files that I want to tar up contain spaces in their name. This means that the `tar` command will delimit based on a spaces, which means that the full file paths will be broken up.

So now I'm trying to make the `find` command return a list of quoted file paths. So here's what I have tried:

```
find . -type f -ctime -30  | xargs printf "\"%s\"\n"
```

But this command also broke up all of the file names based on spaces. So then I tried this:

```
oldifs=$IFS
IFS=\n
find . -type f -ctime -30  | xargs printf "\"%s\"\n"
IFS=$oldifs
```

But this gave me the same results.

Is there a way I can pass the full path names to `tar` and have everything work with spaces in their names?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GNU `tar` has a `-T` option to take the list of files from a specified file.  I would use `find ... -print0 | tar cfzT outfile.tgz - --null` so `tar` receives null-terminated filenames on `stdin`.

Answer (score 1):

The null terminated output piped to `tar`[suggested by geekosaur](https://serverfault.com/questions/276817/returning-a-list-of-quoted-files-paths-using-find/276818#276818) should do the trick, but you can also do this with the `-exec` option of find. Find knows that this is a tough problem so they solved it, you just have to turn things around backwards from what you first tried to do with `tar … $(find …)` and use `find` to call `tar` instead like this:

```
find . -type f -ctime -30 -exec tar cfz outfile.tgz {} +
```

Comment: Problem: If the list of files grows too long, `tar` will run more than once, and `outfile.tgz` will end up with only the contents of the last run. Go with geekosaur's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it. You need to escape \n like $'\n' to assign a new line to a variable.

```
oifs=$IFS; IFS=$'\n'; tar cvf foo.tar $(find ~/POD -type f -ctime -30); IFS=$oifs
```

See the Quoting section of the bash man page for more information.